# Comparing acidity between 4-hydroxybenzaldehyde and 2-hydroxybenzaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, ph

1. https://hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB0011718
2. https://hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB0034170
   The above two links provide the pKa values for the 4-hydroxybenzaldehyde (pKa = 7.32) and 2-hydroxybenzaldehyde (pKa = 8.4) ...
   (not sure as to how reliable the source is)

How do I compare their acidic nature? In either cases there's an electron withdrawing group (aldehyde) at ortho and para position, conjugate base is stabilised either way.
How would the meta- isomer differ from the acidity comparison?

Comment: Consider interaction of groups in ortho position. // Note that questions should be as self-contained as reasonably possible. Links should merely be just data references or source of further study, if the relevant part of link target content can be written as quoted text, eventually formatted by SE Markdown or MathJax/mhchem.